# How can I combine two similar grouped result sets into one?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a couple SQL Server 2012 queries working but cannot figure out how to combine them into a single result set. I would like to see [Total Claims] and [Reversed Claims] as adjacent columns in the same result set. Is this possible?

```
select [Date], DATENAME(weekday, [Date]) as [Day], [Total Claims]
from (Select [Date], count(*) as [Total claims] from ClaimHistoryView group by [Date] )
as CountByDay
order by [Date] desc

select [Date], DATENAME(weekday, [Date]) as [Day], [Reversed Claims]
from (Select [Date], count(*) as [Reversed Claims] from ClaimHistoryView where status = 2 group by [Date] ) as CountByDay
order by [Date] desc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to combine the two queries using a 'union all' with another column indicating where the data comes from and then doing a selective pivot. Hmm. complicated explanation (sorry, german)

This should do the trick

```
select [Date], 
       DATENAME(weekday, [Date]) as [Day], 
       sum(case when Source = 1 then value else 0 end) as [Total Claims],
       sum(case when Source = 2 then value else 0 end) as [Reversed Claims]
from
(
  select 
        1 as source, 
        [Date], 
        count(*) as value 
  from  ClaimHistoryView 
  group by [Date]
union all
  select 
        2 as source,
        [Date],  
        count(*) as value 
  from  ClaimHistoryView 
  where status = 2 
  group by [Date]
) as CountByDay 
Group by [Date]
order by [Date] desc
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Note there was a comma needed after "2 as source".